# Global energy conservation in 3D Burgers' equation?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Is the energy $\| u \|^2_{L^2}$ a conserved quantity for the 3D Burgers' equation for smooth solutions that decay rapidly?

Finite time singularities can appear, but I am interested in the behavior BEFORE the the blow-ups.

The 3D Burgers' equation 
$ {\partial v \over \partial t} + (v \cdot \nabla) v =0 $
can be written as $Dv/Dt =0$ where $D/Dt$ is the material derivative. The  energy density $v^2$ is thus advected, i.e. the energy is conserved "locally".

But is it conserved globally?

Specifically, is the norm $\| u \|_{L^2}$ a conserved quantity? In 1D it is easy to show that the equivalent quantity is conserved, but in 3D I am not so sure.

Either way, I would like a proof, or reference, etc. so that I can see it for myself.

(I am concerned only about smooth and rapidly decaying solutions...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The answer is no in general. Here is an example. 
   Let $f(r,t)$ be a classical solution to the
   1-dimensional Burger's equation $f_t+ff_r=0$, defined for $r>0$ and 
   some interval $0\le t\le T$, and $f$ having compact support in $0<r<\infty$.
   Then denote $r=|x|$ as the radial distance in $R^3$, and set
   $$ u(x,t) = \frac{x}{r}f(r,t).$$
   Then $u$ is a solution to the 3D Burger's equation, smooth during $0\le t\le T$.
   But the energy is not conserved, because
   $$ \int_{R^3}|u|^2\,dx = 4\pi\int_0^\infty f^2(r,t)r^2\,dr,
   $$
   which is not known to be independent of $t$ (It is $\int f^2\,dr$ which is.)
2. The answer is yes for an incompressible solution, i.e. if the
   divergence of $u$ is 0. The reason is that 
   $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{R^3}|u|^2\,dx
    = -2\int_{R^3} u\cdot(u\cdot\nabla u)\,dx.$$
   The integrand on the right is equal to
   $$
    {\rm div\,}\left(\frac{1}{2}|u|^2u\right)-\frac{1}{2}|u|^2{\rm div\,}u.
   $$
   By the divergence theorem, the first term integrates to 0 for rapidly vanishing functions, and
   the second is 0 for incompressible $u$.

Edit: but I don't know whether there
are any solutions in case 2, other than $u=0$. There are many of the type described in 1.

Comment: Point 2 above is correct. I checked myself (it is like the Navier-Stokes case).

Comment: I will check point 1 carefully within a couple days and get back. But your answer is more or less what I had intuited. I am extremely busy until next friday, but will return by soon after if not before.

Comment: I am back and checked out (1). Excellent. I am also glad the community gave the bounty.